# Multiple registrations for the same decorator in a call chain

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I am using SimpleInjector for dependency injection and I've just discovered that I can register the same decorator multiple times within a single call chain and the decorator will be applied as per the requested configuration. For example I can insert my RepositoryTraceDecorator as the first and last decorator of my repository class:

```
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IRepository<>), 
    typeof(RepositoryTraceDecorator<>));
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IRepository<>),
    typeof(RepositoryDetectChangesDecorator<>));
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IRepository<>),
    typeof(CrossRepositoryTransactionScopeDecorator<>));
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IRepository<>),
    typeof(RepositoryTraceDecorator<>));
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IRepository<>),
    typeof(RepositoryExceptionDecorator<>));
```

Is this by design and therefore can I depend on this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this by design and therefore can I depend on this feature?

As you just shown, it can be useful to apply decorators multiple times in the chain and changing this behavior in a future release would be a breaking change. I can ensure you that you can safely depend on this and this behavior won't change.

What might happen in the future is that the new [Diagnostics feature](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/431684) gets improved to detect this and warns you about having multiple identical decorators.